# ionic/cordova - can I disable webview SetJavaScriptEnabled(True)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

A security report of a customer refused my Ionic 4 app saying this is a critical vulnerability.

Here is the details of report.

[image]

So, is it possible to disable it since Ionic is a webview based app?

How can I do this?